# How to handle Out Of Memory Exception Loops in Windows Service

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, out-of-memory

I developed a .net 4.0 windows services that works on large size DataSet. I known that DataSet is not the best way to load large amount of data, in the mean time I re engineer my application, I would like to know the best way to manage OutOfMemoryException, because after the first time that the exception is thrown, it occurs for all following tasks that windows service launch. I think that after the out of memory exception it thrown for current task the memory used by the task in not clean by GC.

My scenario in something similar to

```
public partial class MyWinService : ServiceBase
{
    DBService service;
    IEnumerable<long> unfinishedRequests;
    List<long> activeRequests;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       timer1.Elapsed += Timer_Tick;
        timer1.Start();
        activeRequests = new List<MyTask>();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            MyTask task = GetNewScheduledAppointment();
           If(task != null)
             activeRequests.Add(task);

           task = GetTaskToRun(activeRequests);
           If(task != null)   
            RunTask(task );
    }

      private IRunNowToken RunTask(ServiceTask serviceTask)
        {


            ProcessRunner runner = CreateProcessRunner(serviceTask);

            TaskFactory ts = new TaskFactory(serviceTask.TokenSource.Token);
            ts.StartNew(() => { }).ContinueWith((Task tsk) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    AddTask(serviceTask, tsk);
                    try
                    {
                        runner.Run();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        RemoveTask(serviceTask);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    HandleException(e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    FinalizeRunAlarm(alarm);
                }
            }, serviceTask.TokenSource.Token);

            return serviceTask.RunToken;
        }
```

OutOfMemory Excpetion is managed by RunTask. How can I modify it to be sure that memory of current task will be cleaned?

Thanks

Comment: You need to find your memory leak. Plenty of guides to doing that online. It's not that the GC isn't doing it's job - it's that so far as the GC is concerned, all of the memory is *still in use*.

Comment: Yes I know I have  to resolve memory leak, but in the meantine I'm working on it I need a workround to clean memory of Task that has generated the out of memory exception. Now windows service is running but every time a new task is executed it thrown a new out of memory exception, even if it don't requires a lot of memory

Comment: You "clean memory" by identifying which objects are being kept alive via which references and then ensure that those references don't outlive the usefulness of the objects they refer to. Which is the same as saying, you locate the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that fixing Memory leak is the correct way to fix this issue.

But as you said, meanwhile Please check if this works:

If you are running a 64 bit OS and  RAM + VM > 4GB, goto Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox and then try running the app.

If you get the same exception even after trying this, then I think you might have to start working on Re-Engineering your code.

Comment: I forgot to write that my application is compiled with  x86 setting... the issue is raised only on one pc in production envinroment which has a lot of data to be stored in dataset so after thousands of cicle if cleaning of not use memory doesn't work properly memory leak occurs... Meanwhile  I fix the issue I need  Windows service continue his working or restart himself